# Correct way of breaking code up for ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-router

I'll start by apologizing for the unclear title, and hope the issue becomes clear after my explanation.

The issue I am having is this; I created an object (GameCat) and would like to populate it using an array. Later, I'd like to be able to populate it using a database (FireBase), but that's irrelevant for now.

Gamecat:

```
 var React = require('react');
 var Badge = require('./badge');

 module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
   return <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div className="thumbnail">
     <img src={this.props.imageUrl} alt="..."></img>
     <div className="caption">
      <h3>{this.props.header}</h3>
      <p>{this.props.description}</p>
      <p>
        <Badge title={this.props.title} number={this.props.number} />
      </p>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 }
});
```

Game-list:

```
  var React = require('react');
  var Header = require('./header');
  var Gamecat = require('./gamecat');

  module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

      var list = this.props.thumbnailData.map(function(thumbnailProps){
        return <Gamecat {...thumbnailProps} />
      });

      return <div className="row panel panel-defualt">
        <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <h2 className="text-center">
            Welcome to Project Sophia
          </h2>

          <Header />
          <div>
            {list}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    }
  });
```

Badge:

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button">
      {this.props.title} <span className="badge">{this.props.number}</span>
    </button>
  }
});
```

This is the array:

```
var options = {
  thumbnailData:  [{
    title: 'Show Benchmarks',
    number: 120,
    header: 'Fallout 4',
    description: 'Fallout 4 is an open world action role-playing video game developed by Bethesda Game Studios and published by Bethesda Softworks. The fifth major installment in the Fallout series...',
    imageUrl: 'https://imgrszr-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/1_400--5c49c9942a51f3ad29244289a5de762f641b42cc.png'
  },{
    title: 'Show Benchmarks',
    number: 25,
    header: 'Star Wars',
    description: 'Star Wars Galaxies was a Star Wars themed massively multiplayer online role-playing game for Microsoft Windows, developed by Sony Online Entertainment and published by LucasArts.',
    imageUrl: 'https://levelwhimsicality.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/swg_02.png'
  }]
};
```

In the test website I created, I have the array sitting in app.jsx, and right below it I have

```
var element = React.createElement(Gamelist, options);
ReactDOM.render(element, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

This works perfectly and thus I considered the test page to be a success. The issue showed up when I attempted to move this structure to the main website. I'm using react-router to make the changes between pages so that might add to the problem. I've attempted to put the array with game-list but I'm unsure how to export that out. I also tried to create a separate file for options but that didn't work either. I keep getting an error : `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of exports`.

The code was created based on this: https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReactCasts/tree/master/thumbnail-gulp

Anyhelp would be really appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: Where is the error firing in your code? Also, can you link the badge code?

Comment: I added the code for badge, to the post. Regarding the error, it seems like wherever I put the createElement is where the issue occurs.

Comment: Now it seems like it's coming from game-list.

Comment: Try console logging `list` in `GameList` and paste what you get

Comment: I think I found what the issue is. I am put the array `options` it's own file, and required it into `game-list` but now I get `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. I tried setting up a getInitialState but that didn't seem to solve it. Does that help?

Comment: If you're storing it as JSON in a separate file, you'll have to parse it first using `JSON.parse`

Comment: @ekarni if you're requiring the options, it would return an object. the required object might look something like this `var options = require('./options');` then `options` would look like `Object {thumbnailData: Array[2]}`. Since it's an object, it doesn't have `map` defined. Try passing in `option.thumnailData` instead of `options`. What does your `main.js` look like with the router?

Comment: @Road, that is a fantastic explanation thank you. After a few minutes of fiddling around with the code, I managed to get it to work! Like you said `this.props.thumbnailData.map` wouldn't work, so I changed it to `Options.gamecatData.map` and it worked. Thanks!